# Does this nasty non linear ODE have any "nice" solutions?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations

The ODE is the following:

$$y' = y^4 + \dfrac{(y')^2}{1-y^2}$$

I've been trying to solve it but obviously had no luck. I'm not sure whether it can even be solved analitically, so any help even on seeing the behavior of $y$ might be helpful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Solve it via quadratic equation:

$$y' = \frac{1\pm \sqrt{1+4y^4/(1-y^2)}}{2}.$$

Grouping the $y$'s together, you can [evaluate the integral](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Integrate%5B(1%2BSqrt%5B1-4y%5E2%2F(1-y%5E2)%5D)%5E(-1),y%5D) in $y$, in terms of elliptic functions. The solution will not be pretty.

Answer (score 1):

$$y' = y^4 + \dfrac{(y')^2}{1-y^2}$$
This equation is of the form $y'=f(y)$
$$y'(1-y^2) = y^4-y^6 + y'^2$$
$$ y'^2-y'(1-y^2)= y^6-y^4  $$
$$ (y'-\frac 12(1-y^2))^2= y^6-y^4 + \frac 14(1-y^2)^2$$
$$ \frac {dy}{dx}=\frac 12(1-y^2)\pm \sqrt{ y^4(y^2-1) + \frac 14(1-y^2)^2}$$
$$ \frac {dy}{dx}=\frac 12(1-y^2) \pm \sqrt{ (y^2-1)(y^4 + \frac 14(y^2-1))}$$
The integral cant be expressed with elementary functions

Comment: But at least by analyzing the sign of this function of $y$ you should hopefully be able to answer the part of the question about the behavior of solutions.

Comment: Surely @DanielSchepler

Answer (score 0):

Would you consider $y=0$ to be a nice solution?

Comment: Yes, but naturally I asked the question looking for non trivial solutions.